# Getting all questions with a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, questions, api

The Stack Exchange API supports `/questions/{id}/tags/{tags}` but it returns only a selection of questions available on Stack Overflow.

For a school project I need to find all questions containing the tag [swift](/questions/tagged/swift).

I know there is a `has_more` element but I have no idea on how to create the complete list of questions without getting duplicates.

Any suggestions on how I can do this? (I am using JavaScript.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For tags such as [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) which have more than 100 questions, there is no way to get all of the questions in a single request, because the SE API will return at most 100 questions per request. There shouldn't be such a way to get all the results in a single request, because returning huge numbers of questions from a single request (there are 305,000 [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) questions) isn't reasonable for multiple design and resource allocation reasons.

However, you can get all of the results by making more requests. The API does support paging, by giving back a field called `has_more` in the response. If the value of that field is *true*, then there are more results than fit in the maximum number of results you specified in the `pagesize` parameter (max 100 for almost all SE API methods). If you want additional results, you should send another similar request, but specifying a different `page`. For example, to get the second page of results of questions tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), send a GET request to [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=2`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=2).

Repeat this in a loop, incrementing `page` each time, until the `has_more` field in the response is false.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: Make sure to never go over your quota, and if the response contains `backoff`  field, wait the given value, in seconds, before sending another request. Failing to honor any of these might get you IP banned from using the API.